# reading text portion from list of images and saving in R, using magick

Tags: r, imagemagick, tesseract

Here is the code I'm using for reading a text from multiple images in my list but after image resizing I want to save the output into separate folders with exact name.

```
library(magick)
library(magrittr)
    test <- image_read(list) %>%
      image_crop("100x16+161+68")%>%
      image_resize("2000") %>%
      image_convert() %>%      
      image_trim() %>%
      image_ocr()
    cat(test)
```

As far as I figured out, there is something I could do to save image, unique names with "image_write". I would be thankful for any suggestions and help, and hope it would be very helpful for new users as well. If it's possible I need to create a batch of about 100 images for a large data set.

```
 image_write(list, path = "/data/backup", format = "png") %>%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
library(magick)
library(purrr)

save_image <- function(img, img_name, output_dir) {
  image_write(img, file.path(output_dir, basename(img_name)))
  img
}

fils <- list.files("/tmp/so", pattern="png$", full.names = TRUE)

map(fils, ~{
  curr_fil <- .x
  image_read(curr_fil) %>%
    image_crop("100x16+161+68") %>%
    image_resize("2000") %>%
    save_image(curr_fil, "/tmp/backup") %>% 
    image_convert() %>%      
    image_trim() %>%
    image_ocr()
}) -> ocr_result
```

There's no real need to make a function but it makes the pipes cleaner. This way you can have a pipe element with a side effect but keep processing.

Comment: I run the code there are few issues with it, if folder has only one image it works great but for 2 images it works 4 times and for 3 images it reads for 9 times and like that. and second problem is that it only save first image in backup folder with different names i want to save every processed image with their original names hope you would be able to sort out these issues and thanks for feedback

Comment: Indeed. give that edit a go. (that was a _very_ helpful/descriptive note about the malfunctioning code #ty)

Comment: yap thats just perfect now thank you so very much i would not able to do without you